# The App Delegate applicationSignificantTimeChange random invocation

Tags: ios

The App Delegate applicationSignificantTimeChange is invoked every hour or so. Any idea why?

Comment: The docs state that : "Examples of significant time changes include the arrival of midnight, an update of the time by a carrier, and the change to daylight savings time." - maybe your carrier updates the time hourly? Though it would be strange. Can you show any code, though as this is called by the system, it is hard to say which part is relevant. Have you tried posting this/searching on Apple developer forums?

Comment: I simply use the app delegate funcapplicationSignificantTimeChange(_ application: UIApplication) 
and record in my diagnostics every time its invoked. My provider is AT&T - why they would updates so often? Wander if other people with same provider have similar experience.